# how to allow unregistred users to view normal posts

Tags: user-registration, user-roles, permissions

If an unregistered user/stranger try to view a post it says

> "You must be registered or logged in to view the post".

http://testandverification.com/events/dvclub-august-2012-on-sv-uvm/

We have a category (for private posts) to allow only some registered users to access some posts.

Even though posts are not included in that category, it shows the above message.

> How to allow unregistered users/strangers to view public posts?

I did the following on my test server.

**I disabled all the plugins and switched my theme to twentyeleven.**

> In that twentyeleven theme everything is fine - stranger can able to
>   access posts.

**When I switch the theme to our custom theme and without enabling the plugins, the issue re-occurs.**

Then I thought that the problem is not with plugin so I tried to compare the theme code with an early release and found that it is the same as before.

> I loaded a old DB backup in the test server and I was
>   surprised that it worked correctly!
>
> When I tried to recreate the missing posts between the old DB
>   and current DB, I got the same problem.
>
> It is strange and I felt happy when I traced the problem in the DB and
>   now I have lost the confidence of tracing the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a strange and rare bug.

> While publishing our last post we checked the "Blog" and some other
>   categories in the category section.
>
> In our previous posts we never checked the "Blog" category.

Initially, when I tried to reproduce the bug, I didn't noticed it.

We again tried to reproduce the bug and this time we have identified the bug.

**I am not sure whether the bug is in wordpress or our site development team.**

**I wonder how checking a category affects the behavior of "Strangers"!**

> If any one know where the bug actually lies, please let me know.

We have corrected the problem in our site and the above link is now working fine.